# Simplifying repeated code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

It there a best practice to simplify something like the following in React?

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    checkbox1: false,
    checkbox2: false,
    checkbox3: false,
    ...
  };
},

selectCheckbox1: function () {
  this.setState({
    checkbox1: !this.state.checkbox1
  });
},

selectCheckbox2: function () {
  this.setState({
    checkbox2: !this.state.checkbox2
  });
},

selectCheckbox3: function () {
  this.setState({
    checkbox3: !this.state.checkbox3
  });
},

...

render: function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkbox1} onChange={this.selectCheckbox1} />
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkbox2} onChange={this.selectCheckbox2} />
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkbox3} onChange={this.selectCheckbox3} />
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, I can use an array for the state instead of individual fields and create a generic function that takes an index parameter to distinguish which checkbox to update:

```
const Checkboxes = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      checkboxes: [false, false, false, ...]
    };
  },

  selectCheckbox: function (index) {
    let checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes.slice();
    checkboxes[index] = !checkboxes[index];
    this.setState({
      checkboxes: checkboxes
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkboxes[0]} onChange={() => this.selectCheckbox(0)} />
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkboxes[1]} onChange={() => this.selectCheckbox(1)} />
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkboxes[2]} onChange={() => this.selectCheckbox(2)} />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I am new to React and JavaScript so I don't know exactly the tradeoffs happening behind the scenes here. Is the second an improvement over the first? Which is preferred and why?

Comment: This question is still showing as  unsolved. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkboxes: {
        cheese: false,
        lettuce: false,
        tomatoe: false
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const checkboxId = e.target.id;
    this.setState({
      checkboxes: {
        ...this.state.checkboxes,
        [checkboxId]: !this.state.checkboxes[checkboxId]
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.entries(this.state.checkboxes).map(([key, val]) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={val}
                id={key}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <label>
                {key}
              </label>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This makes things more explicit and easier to follow and has the added benefit of not creating a new anonymous function each time you render.

Comment: what are the drawbacks of creating a new anonymous function on each render? when are they garbage collected?

Comment: @JoshBroadhurst it is a best practice to allow the underlying component to compare props in `shouldComponentUpdate`. Anonymous functions will always be different

Comment: ok, got it. thanks. you still have an anonymous function in your map call (`([key, val]) => {...}`) but that is not passed as a prop. how does that anonymous function affect the render cycle?

Comment: it's called every render cycle, that's all

Comment: is there a reason to use `handleChange = e => {` instead of `handleChange: function (e) {`

Comment: if i'm not able to use ES6 destructuring with spread attributes, would I need to make a shallow copy of checkboxes state object with [`_.clone`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone) inside `handleChange`?

Comment: arrow functions are bound to the lexical scope, so that we can safely use `this` in the handler without binding it explicitly. 
You can use `Object.assign` instead of spread attributes

Answer (score 3):

Second one is definitely better approach then the first one. You can safely go with that.

Apart from that, you can also render the check box without repeating them each time in render function by using array map.

```
render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.checkboxes.map((c, i) => {
             return (
              <input key={i} type="checkbox" checked={c} onChange={() => this.selectCheckbox(i)} />
           );
         })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer having the checkboxes named (in an object, not an array), like in your first example. But that could vary by use case. Having them unnamed as an array does, as [Prakash-sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7232300/prakash-sharma) points out,  provide the benefit of being able to map over them.

This is how I would do it to reduce the duplication of the callback function declarations (without storing the checkbox values in an array):

```
const Checkboxes = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      checkbox1: false,
      checkbox2: false,
      checkbox3: false
    };
  },

  selectCheckbox: function (checkboxNr) {
    // return a callback with the checkboxNr set
    return () => {
        this.setState({
         [checkboxNr]: !this.state[checkboxNr]
        });
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    const {checkboxes1, checkboxes2, checkboxes3} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checkboxes1} onChange={ this.selectCheckbox("checkbox1") } />
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checkboxes2} onChange={ this.selectCheckbox("checkbox2") } />
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checkboxes3} onChange={ this.selectCheckbox("checkbox3") } />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this syntax: `const {checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3} = this.state;`

Comment: Does returning an anonymous function from a named function for onChange prop have the same garbage collection performance issues as using anonymous functions directly in onChange prop?

Comment: @JoshBroadhurst.
Sure, perhaps I should have mentioned that. It's [ES6 destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_overview-destructuring), in this case for objects.

``this.state`` is an object containing several properties. With the line you quoted we pick out the properties that match the names checkbox1, checkbox2 and checkbox3. They are then available as variables in the scope.
It's the equivalent of writing 
`const checkbox1 = this.state.checkbox1; const checkbox2 = this.state.checkbox2` etc.

Comment: @JoshBroadhurst Regarding garbage collection I don't know, but my guess would be that they have similar behavior. But I would also guess that in most cases garbage collection wouldn't be an issue either way. (Though that's talking from veeery limited experience.)